# Control Data Modeler DDL output to support SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm finding there are a lot of instances where Oracle's Data Modeler will generate DDL that will not run in Oracle's sqlplus:

When a RDBMS comment contains a semicolon:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE DIM_Date
IS
  'restricted to
where d1.NextDate >= to_date(''01/01/2010'',''DD/MM/YYYY'');' ;
```

The above fails with 
*ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated*

When a comment contains a blank line:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE DIM_Date
IS
  'restricted to

where d1.NextDate >= to_date(''01/01/2010'',''DD/MM/YYYY'')';
```

It tries to interpret the next line as a new statement (I tried set sqlblanklines off but this did not help for this case).

I went into the data modeler model and changed the comments to remove these items.  But I noticed when I execute these scripts in sql developer that they do in fact run without issue.

Is there an option in sqlplus to be more friendly to string parsing or is there an option in data modeler to output ddl that sqlplus won't choke on?

Comment: don't think so, but this should work fine in SQLcl

Comment: that is SET SQLBLANKLINES ON in sqlcl will let you do what you're doing

you could also write a transformation script or use global search/replace to remove the blank lines from your data model comments

Comment: I did consider sqlcl, though it's another dependency on my script (and the developers already have sqlplus), but maybe 200 MB is worth it to avoid this little odities

Comment: sqlcl is 20MB, not 200 :) And it's faster than SQL*Plus at running scripts...and you can use it in things like Hudson for your automation tasks

Comment: Ooops :).  But it also requires a jre.  The reason sqlplus is favored is because I know the developer will have it (it comes with the visual studio tools that are required to open the project).  SQLcl is another dependency that would either have to be checked in to source control or noted as a dependency.  None of these items are insurmountable, I'm just trying to find the easiest path to "checkout and go" - so your automation comment is well timed.  If I have to check in 20 mb worth of stuff, maybe that's the best option.  Or maybe I'll turn it into a nuget package.

Comment: or tell your devs to quit putting blank lines in their object comments :) Actually they should be applauded for writing comments in genera!

Comment: yeah that's the rub with this - fully documented data model in data modeler has a hard time getting into the database, but something that's half put together would have no problem :P